# aws sam: How to view the command run while running the docker image

Tags: docker, aws-sam

I am checking on `AWS SAM`.

I have setup a `HelloWorld` example for `python3.7` runtime

I have started the server:

```
sam local start-api
```

When i try to access the endpoint `localhost/3000/hello` it downloads an image `public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-python3.7:rapid-1.40.0-x86_64`

and mount the build folder inside the container

```
Mounting /home/testuser/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
```

I see the container is run using the command.

```
"/var/rapid/aws-lambda-rie --log-level error"
```

what does this do.

How to see the full docker run command run by sam